# Detecting active window in an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, focus, onblur

I want to know why this url `http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/demo/2007-05-16-detect-browser-window-focus/`
When opened separately this does work well.

is not being blurred when it is being loaded in the iframe `http://speedywap.com/ihome/?url=`

> [Test URL](http://speedywap.com/ihome/?url=http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/demo/2007-05-16-detect-browser-window-focus/)

The strange this is that when you click on the iframe and click back on the main page it is blurred but else it isn't.

Look at the screenshots below
[image: When the iframe is loaded the first time]

[image: Clicking the iframe and then the bar]

What I don't get is why isn't the iframe blurred from the initial load as only one window can be active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `blur` event on the page inside the iframe doesn't occur because the document in the iframe never had `focus` in the first place.

When you initially load the page, the iframe and its content are loaded but are not given `focus`. Therefore no `blur` event can happen on page load.

Comment: So to solve this I should set the initial active state as blurred. Which means that if it wasn't loaded in an iframe the blur would be removed automatically whereas if it was, it would require the user to be active.

Comment: nice answer 1 up vote for you for such a fine observation and accepted answer because you answered my question. Thanks